# python program is printing out gibberish after having never done this before

Tags: python

I have been using a python pandas via pandas module to change the prices of a large dataset of books. I receive retail updates and I have to update the prices and discounts of the book every week. Here is the code that I have been using with no issues (until recently):

```
    def pricechange():
       global inventorynews, inventoryupds
       inventorynews=pd.read_excel(r'\theofficialbookinventoryayg21.xlsx')
       inventoryupds = pd.read_excel(r'\_retail_update_20230828 
       (2).xlsx')
    for idx, row in inventoryupds.iterrows():
         inventorynews.loc[inventorynews['ISBN'] == row['ISBN'], 'retail'] = row['retail']
    for idx, row in inventoryupds.iterrows():
         inventorynews.loc[inventorynews['ISBN'] == row['ISBN'], 'discount'] = row['discount']    
    

   inventorynews.to_csv('thofficialbookinventoryayg28.csv')
   pricechange()
```

This code would return substituted valuesinto the discount and retail column without issue. I have been doing this for months. However, the last few weeks I have been getting gibberish in some rows/columns that look like this:

```
  Rows with string values in 'retail' column:
                                         Unnamed: 0.6  \
  165559  ™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã‚Â¦ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã¢...   
  227094  ‚ÂÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã‚Â¦ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡...   
  527388  ovides new strategic commentaries from leaders...
```

The information in the row/column is all out of orders and it is just really odd. I have no clue why this is happening. Does anyone know why this could possibly be an issue when it was never one before? The retail file that has the updated discount/pricing is still in the same format.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the data but my first guess would be that the format of the updated  xlsx file has changed.  Take the rows where "retail" has strings and use the corresponding ISBNs to look at the values in the updated Excel file.  My guess is you will see something unexpected.